# When 2 svn:external collide

Tags: svn

If two projects both have svn:external set up to get the same external directories, what happens if you check them both out in a way they both want to put the same directory to the same location on disk? Is it just doing a regular SVN check-out/update and thus will happily work, i.e the 2nd project checkout will see the external directory is already up to date?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Externals go inside the working copy, and you cannot check out multiple projects into the same working copy.

**Edit:** when you try to use .. to put the target of the externals above the directory where the externals is defined on you get:

```
svn propset svn:externals "^/test ../test" .
svn: Invalid svn:externals property on '.': target '../test' is an absolute path or involves '..'
```

Comment: Oh, did I misunderstand the flexibility of externals... can they only put the external dirs inside the main WC, not say at "../dependencies/"

Comment: yeah, it's a security problem if it were allowed to go outside of the working directory (think ..\..\..\..\windows\\)